# Parse result of batch script output in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, ms-office

I am trying to retrieve the Microsoft Office version using the following command:

```
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer"
```

this returns the following output:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer

   (Default)    REG_SZ    Word.Application.15
```

I need to parse the output and match the version using the following table and paste the final version into a text file.

> Office 97   -  7.0
>   Office 98   -  8.0
>   Office 2000 -  9.0
>   Office XP   - 10.0
>   Office 2003 - 11.0
>   Office 2007 - 12.0
>   Office 2010 - 14.0
>   Office 2013 - 15.0
>   Office 2016 - 16.0

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided a similar answer in your previous, *although seemingly ignored*, question on Outlook.

There may be a way using the registry, *(although only for Office 2007 onwards)*:

```cmd
@Echo Off

If "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%"=="86" (If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
        Set "KEY=\Wow6432Node" & Set "MWB=64") Else (Set "MWB=32" & Set "MOB=32"
    )) Else Set "MWB=64"
Set "KEY=HKLM\Software%KEY%\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" 

Set "GUID="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Reg Query %KEY% /K /F "*-001B-*0FF1CE}"') Do (
    If Not Defined GUID Set "GUID=%%~nxA")
If Not "%GUID:~-1%"=="}" Set "GUID="
If Not Defined GUID (Echo= Unable to find Office Product & GoTo EndIt)

If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 4 Set "IOV=10" Else (If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 2 (Set "IOV=07"
    If Not Defined MOB Set "MOB=32") Else (If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 5 (Set "IOV=13"
        ) Else (If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 6 Set "IOV=16")))

If Not Defined IOV (Echo= Unknown Office version on your %MWB%-bit OS
    GoTo EndIt)

If Not Defined MOB Set "MOB=32"
If %GUID:~20,1% Equ 1 Set "MOB=64"

Echo=&Echo= Office 20%IOV% %MOB%-bit Product installed on a %MWB%-bit OS

:EndIt
Timeout 5 1>Nul
```

*This has not been tested because I have never been able to justify the cost of any Microsoft Office product.*

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=5* skip=1 delims=. " %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer"') do set "wver=%%a.0"


for %%# in ("Office 97-7.0" "Office 98-8.0" "Office 2000-9.0" "Office XP-10.0" "Office 2003-11.0" "Office 2007-12.0" "Office 2010-14.0"  "Office 2013-15.0" "Office 2016-16.0") do (

    for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%a in ("%%~#") do (

        if %%b equ %wver%  ( 
            set ov=%%a
        )
    )
)

echo %ov%
```

But you have pretty old versions of the MS Office which can be installed only on windows xp (or even older versions of windows) where the `reg` command is not available. So you can also check [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/other/officeVersion.bat) which uses `FTYPE` command to determine the office version